# long long int in ObjC

Tags: c, objective-c, integer, long-integer

I am using this NSURLConnection Delegate method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    long long rdata = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"Response Length : %lld", rdata);    
}
```

its always showing -1

What is the format specifier for long long variable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs on [`expectedContentLength`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLResponse/expectedContentLength):

> **Return Value**
>
> The receiver’s expected
>   content length, or
>   `NSURLResponseUnknownLength` if the
>   length can’t be determined.

`NSURLResponseUnknownLength` [is equals to -1](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Have you tried inspecting the content-length header? The server you're connecting to is likely using a [chunked transfer encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), so the content-length is not available.

Comment: >I suspect NSURLResponseUnknownLength is -1.

Yep. See the bottom of http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLResponse_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I fished around a bit to find it, but the Apple search didn't help me.